# Magento 2: How do I notify a customer about an order status change done via the REST Api?

Tags: magento2, api, email, rest-api, order-status

I'm using the rest API

```
.../index.php/rest/V1/orders/561/
```

in order to update my order status:

Payload (POST):

```
{
  "entity": {
    "entity_id": 561,
    "state": "new",
    "status": "pending"
  }
}
```

That works fine, but it's not triggering an order status email. Looking into the full payload I don't see any option to trigger the email. Triggering the comments API is triggering a email but it is not the status change email. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the salesOrderManagementV1 to add a comment to an order email and send an email:

```
POST /V1/orders/{id}/comments
POST /V1/orders/{id}/emails
```

Some details from the code:

```
<route url="/V1/orders/:id/emails" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="notify"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

You can also add a comment in that email:

```
<route url="/V1/orders/:id/comments" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface" method="addComment"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Sales::sales" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Digging into the API code:

```
/**
 * Adds a comment to a specified order.
 *
 * @param int $id The order ID.
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderStatusHistoryInterface $statusHistory Status history comment.
 * @return bool
 */
public function addComment($id, \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderStatusHistoryInterface $statusHistory);

/**
 * Emails a user a specified order.
 *
 * @param int $id The order ID.
 * @return bool
 */
public function notify($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have been updating the order status while setting comments with salesOrderManagementV1 as per the [Swagger](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/) reference. Setting it with an empty comment still triggers the email, but with comments it's optional based on the POST body content:

```
{
  "statusHistory": {
    "comment": "string",
    "created_at": "string",
    "entity_id": 0,
    "entity_name": "string",
    "is_customer_notified": 0,
    "is_visible_on_front": 0,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "status": "string",
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```